# How to reduce read operations on Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, instance, snapshot

As a passionate high-school teacher, I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore & Flutter for my read-only app. My data is about 2000 image.png files with some tags as categories and subcategories. Categories, subcategories and images have an order among themselves. Reason of me using Cloud Firestore is, I can change (= add, delete, update) my categories subcategories and images anytime and my user will be able update with my latest content.

So far everything works fine, my app is fully functional offline, I can synchronize with my content, but if device is online, all the documents in Firestore has been read every time even if there is no change in db. That makes me think that I am doing a huge mistake.

This is the code for what happens when app is opened:

```
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: _getCategories(),
      builder: (context, catSnapshot) {

            if((!catSnapshot.hasData) && !catSnapshot.hasError) return customProgressIndicator("Categories Synchronizing");

        if(_categories.isNotEmpty) _categories.clear();
        _categories = catSnapshot.data.documents.map<Category>((document) => Category.fromJson(document.data)).toList();

        return FutureBuilder(
          future: _getSubCategories(),
          builder: (context, subSnapshot) {
            if(!subSnapshot.hasData && !subSnapshot.hasError) return customProgressIndicator("Subcategories Synchronizing");

            if(_subcategories.isNotEmpty) _subcategories.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<_categories.length; i++) {
              String catName = _categories[i].name;
              List<Subcategory> subcategoriesI = subSnapshot.data.documents.where((document) => document.data["catName"]==catName).map<Subcategory>((document) => Subcategory.fromJson(document.data)).toList();
              _subcategories[catName] = subcategoriesI;
            }

            return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _onRefresh,
              child: _categories.length==0 ? whenNoData() : ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => _createCategoryItem(i),
                itemCount: _categories.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              ),         );       },      );    },   )
```

This is my main page:

```
class _CategoryListPageState  extends State<CategoryListPage> {
  List<Category> _categories = [];
  Map<String, List<Subcategory>> _subcategories = {};

 Future<QuerySnapshot> _getCategories() async{

    var conn=await UserHasConnection();
    print("connection: " + conn.toString());
    Future<QuerySnapshot> snapshots;

      if (widget.isUserPro) {
        snapshots = Firestore.instance.collection("categories").where("isPro", isEqualTo: true).orderBy("showOrder").getDocuments();
        snapshots.timeout(Duration(seconds: globalTimeOut), onTimeout: () {print("Timeout Category");});
        return snapshots;
      }   else {
        snapshots = Firestore.instance.collection("categories").orderBy("showOrder").getDocuments();
        snapshots.timeout(Duration(seconds: globalTimeOut), onTimeout: () {print("Timeout Category");});
        return snapshots;
      }
  }

  _getSubCategories() async{
    Future<QuerySnapshot> snapshots;
      if(widget.isUserPro){
    snapshots=Firestore.instance.collection("subcategories").where("isPro", isEqualTo: true).orderBy("showOrder").getDocuments();
        snapshots.timeout(Duration(seconds: globalTimeOut), onTimeout: () {
          print("Timeout Subcategory");
        });
        return snapshots;
      }  else  {  snapshots=Firestore.instance.collection("subcategories").orderBy("showOrder").getDocuments();
        snapshots.timeout(Duration(seconds: globalTimeOut), onTimeout: () {
          print("Timeout Subcategory");
        });
        return snapshots;
      }
  }
```

Those are my Firestore document collections:

```
categories
  isPro: boolean (there aid free and paid-proUser's)
  name: string, name of the category
  scCount: int, number of subcategories it has
  showOrder: its order among other categories

subcategories
  catName: name of the category it belongs to
  fcCount: number of image.png it has
  imageBytes: subcategories have an image
  isPro: boolean, subcategories can also be free or paid
  name: subcategories have a name
  showOrder: each subcategory has an order among other subcategories in that category
  title: title of the subcat, similar to name

flashcards
  backBytes: back image base64encoded
  backStamp
  catName: category of this image belongs to
  frontBytes: front image base64encoded
  frontStamp
  isPro: cards are also free or paid (for search function below)
  name
  showOrder: order of this card in the subcategory
  subName: name of the subcategory that this card belongs to
```

*** I have separate flascards, flashcards2x, flashcards3x collections for different device screen sizes

Also there is a search function which is done from flashcardContents collection frontContent property:

```
flashcardContents
  frontContent
  globalOrder
  isPro
  name
  showOrder
  updateTime
  updateType: (1-adden, 2-updated, 3-deleted)
```

Lastly, my FirebaseService functions:

```
class FlashcardFirebaseService extends IServiceBase {
  Future<List<Flashcard>> QueryRatedFlashCards(List<Flashcard> _flashcards,
      List<String> flashcardNames, String ratioPostfix, bool isUserPro) async {
    var snapshot;
    flashcardNames.forEach((flashcardName) {
      print("flashcardName: " + flashcardName);

      if (isUserPro) {
        //For pro user
        snapshot = Firestore.instance
            .collection("flashcards${ratioPostfix}")
            .where("name", isEqualTo: flashcardName)
            .snapshots();
      } else {
        snapshot = Firestore.instance
            .collection("flashcards${ratioPostfix}")
            .where("name", isEqualTo: flashcardName)
            .where("isPro", isEqualTo: false)
            .snapshots();
      }

      snapshot.listen((onData) {
        _flashcards.addAll(onData.documents
            .map<Flashcard>((document) => Flashcard.fromJson(document.data))
            .toList());
      });
    });
    return _flashcards;
  }

  static Future<List<Category>> SyncCategories(bool isPro, double lastStamp){
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("categories")
        .getDocuments().then((data){
          return data;
    });
  }

  static Future<List<Category>> SyncSubcategories(bool isPro){
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("subcategories")
        .getDocuments().then((data){
      return data;
    });      }  }


class FlashcardSearchService extends IServiceBase {
  static Future SyncLocalSearchDb() async {
    Query baseQuery;
    AppConfig appConfig;
    appConfig = await AppConfigService.GetAppConfiguration().then((appConfig){
      if (appConfig != null) {
        var lastSyncDate;
        try {
          lastSyncDate = appConfig.fcLastSync;
        } catch (ex) {}

        print("lastSyncDate ---------------------------:"+ (lastSyncDate/1000).toString());

        baseQuery = Firestore.instance
            .collection("flashcardContents")
            .where("updateTime", isGreaterThan: lastSyncDate/1000);
      } else {
        appConfig = null;

        print("appConfig null");

        //Create all card contents
        baseQuery = Firestore.instance.collection("flashcardContents");
        appConfig = new AppConfig();
      }

      baseQuery.getDocuments().then((query) {
        query.documents.forEach((doc) => _syncFlashcardContent(doc));
        if(query.documents.length>0)
          {
            appConfig.fcLastSync = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toDouble();
            print("new lastSyncDate ---------------------------:"+ (appConfig.fcLastSync /1000).toString());
            print("SYNC!!! " + appConfig.fcLastSync.toString());
         AppConfigService.UpdateApplicationConfigurationSyncTime(appConfig);

          } else {
              print("CANT SYNC!!! " + appConfig.fcLastSync.toString());
            }
        return appConfig;
      }).timeout(Duration(seconds: globalTimeOut),onTimeout: (){
        print("TimeOutSync");
        return appConfig;
      });
    });
```

To summarize, I have a flashcards image.png collection for my students to use for studying. My content changes to some extent on a weekly basis and I want my users to catch up with me. Problem is, with my code if device is online all document is read constantly even if there is no change and even if I close the app seconds later I open it. This becomes unaffordable for me.

Sorry for long post, I hope at least you like the code, any idea is valuable and appreciated.

I found out that main cause of my app having that much read count is: "If the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query."
So new question is: Is it possible to change the behavior of this listener? Or is there a way to bypass it? I am feel like my app is not so suitable for Firestore but so far this seems to be only problem!

To summerize: I need a listener that works, for example, once in a day, because my collection will change probably once in a day. Or I need a way to by-pass this. For example when my app goes offline, listener does not work. any options to disable my apps network connection without disabling Firestore offline persistence? Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you know the documents are being read even if they are unchanged?  The local cache should be used if there are no changes.

Comment: I keep checking from firebase console, for last 36 hours I opened my app once, then close it on main screen with doing anything, now I have about 500 reads, and I am the only user

Answer (score 4):

It's not really possible for us on Stack Overflow to diagnose the source of all the reads on your database, since we don't understand the total operation of your app (we don't have all your source code, nor do we understand the behavior of your users).  However, a very common source of unexpected reads comes from the Firebase console itself.  When you use the console to browse the database, it will cost you reads in order to populate the console.  If you leave the console window open on a collection that's actively being changes, that will further accumulate reads over time while the console is open.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that leaving console open may cause some read operations, I will keep that in mind. But still, I believe there would be something in the code that works incorrect. Anyway, appreciated.

Comment: After reading your answer again, I realized my collection never changed. So I think there is a problem with my code because right now I have about 100 documents and my read count 858, nothing changed, just opened my app once, no writes, no deletes, no downloads, but 858 reads, I can't understand

Comment: Hey Doug, I think I have to change my question: "If the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query." This is the main cause of my app having increased read counts, my database does not change in every 30 minutes, it rather changes once in a day, so I need a listener works only once in a day. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have a new question, could you simply post it separately?  Stack Overflow doesn't work well when the question changes over time.